# C++ - find function does not work executed on substring

Tags: c++, c++11

I do have got a problem with an algorithm, which I want to use to split command line into several substrings. E.g. the string `"Hello World -n filename"` should be sliced into `"Hello"` `"World"` and `"-n filename"`.

Here is my whole code example:

```
string hello = "Hello World -n filename";
uint64_t startIndex = 0;
uint64_t endIndex = hello.length() - 1;

while(startIndex < endIndex) {
    uint64_t nextWhiteSpaceIndex;
    string value;

    if(hello.at(startIndex) != '-') {

        nextWhiteSpaceIndex = hello.substr(startIndex).find(" ");
        value = hello.substr(startIndex, nextWhiteSpaceIndex);
        cout << value << endl;

    } else {

        nextWhiteSpaceIndex = hello.substr(hello.substr(startIndex).find(" ")).find(" ");
        value = hello.substr(startIndex, nextWhiteSpaceIndex);
        cout << value << endl;

    }
    startIndex = nextWhiteSpaceIndex + 1;
}
```

And I do have problems with this command:

```
nextWhiteSpaceIndex = hello.substr(startIndex).find(" ");
```

This is placed within the while-loop and it seems like the...

```
.substr(startIndex)
```

... part is completely ignored. The first loop run works fine, but during the second/following the nextWhiteSpaceIndex does not get the right next index assigned. It always prints `"Hello" "World" "World" "World" "World"` and continues to print `"World"`.

Do you guys have a hint, why this does not work? I could not find an appropriate explanation during my research through the web.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to inspect your code during runtime?

Comment: Yes, sure. After the first loop run every variable assignment is done correctly. When it comes to assign the nextWhiteSpaceIndex variable, it seems that the find() method is executed on the initial string and not the substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hello` is never changed, yet you're using `find` on only part of it (`substr`), and then calling `substr(startIndex)` on the whole string (`hello`) over and over again.

1. `"Hello World -n filename".find(" ")` -> 5
2. `"World -n filename".find(" ")` -> 5 again ("World" is the same length as "Hello")
3. `"World -n filename".find(" ")` -> 5

You could use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)'s second argument (`size_type pos`) to specify the start offset where to start the search and create fewer temporary strings:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const string hello = "Hello World -n filename";

  size_t startIndex = 0, pos = 0;
  bool eat = true;

  while(true) {
    pos = hello.find('\x20', pos);

    if(pos == string::npos) {
      cout << hello.substr(startIndex) << endl;
      break;
    }
    else if(eat && hello[startIndex] == '-') {
      eat = false;
      ++pos;
      continue;
    }

    cout << hello.substr(startIndex, pos - startIndex) << endl;

    startIndex = ++pos;
    eat = true;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ c++ main.cpp && ./a.out
Hello
World
-n filename
```

Comment: I really like your explanation and your solution. Now it is totally clear, where my error was located.

Thanks, that helped to understand C++ a little bit more!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do something like

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string hello = "Hello World -n filename";

    stringstream ss (hello);
    vector<string> v;
    string s, t;

    while (ss >> s)
    {
        if (s[0] == '-')
        {   
            ss >> t;
            v.push_back (s + " " + t); 
        }   
        else
            v.push_back (s);
    }

    for (auto i : v)
        clog << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
$ ./a.out
Hello
World
-n filename
```

Answer (score 2):

If you output the value for `nextWhiteSpaceIndex` you will always see: 5, 5, 5, 5... It's an index relative to `startIndex`, so simply changing the last line into `startIndex += nextWhiteSpaceIndex + 1;` would probably quickfix the issue.

(Aren't you taking too many substrings? `std::string::find` can take the search start index as argument, so you can perform the whole search on always the same buffer.)